# Copiar celdas a inputs separados

Tags: php, html, input

La idea es copiar una cantidad de `celdas` para luego pegarlas con el mismo formato de separación, me explico en la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Copiar los datos de la hoja de cálculo de google (imagen de la izquierda) y pegarlos en los inputs de `html` (imagen de la derecha), evitando la copia de dato por dato.
No es opción la exportación de los datos ya que la posición de los datos o formato puede variar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo he solucionado ese mismo problema usando la librería JS handsontable y enviando los datos a un archivo PHP, hay una versión gratuita para uso no comercial:
https://handsontable.com/

Existen también alternativas de código libre.

DataTables:
https://datatables.net/

jgrid:
http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

EtherCalc:
https://ethercalc.net/

Backgrid.js:
https://backgridjs.com/

Hay más soluciones comerciales, pero creo que no son mejores que handsontable y esta se puede usar gratis.